# Azure ServiceBusClient, App registrations, "System.UnauthorizedAccessException Unauthorized access"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, permission-denied, servicebus

I'm sending a ServiceBusMessage using the credentials of an Azure "App registration". I have already configured App and added this as service bus contributors.

I get this error:

**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Unauthorized access. 'Send' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource**: 'sb://xxxxxx-eastus.servicebus.windows.net/test'. TrackingId:a3c9cb6f8705406c8028049296deba60_G5, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2022-06-15T18:03:04'

What step could I have missed?

```
    static public void SendTest()
    {
        string AZURE_TENANT_ID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AZURE_TENANT_ID"];
        string AZURE_CLIENT_ID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"];
        string AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"];

        string _serviceBusName = "xxxxxx-eastus";
        string _queueName = "test";

        TokenCredential tkcredential = new ClientSecretCredential(AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET);

        var token = tkcredential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
    new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }), new CancellationToken());

        Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(token));

        var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient($"{_serviceBusName}.servicebus.windows.net", tkcredential);
        var queueSendClient = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(_queueName);

        var MsgTest = new
        {
            name = "Test from moon"
        };

        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MsgTest);
        var message = new ServiceBusMessage(json);

        queueSendClient.SendMessageAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

I Add permissions for full access to azure ServiceBus

[image: App Registration, API permissions]

I add the role as a contributor to service bus

[image: contributor to service bus]

Authorization error, I have been searching on google and trying for more than two hours, and I keep getting the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The application needs the Service Bus Data Sender role. Contributor role only allows management of the resource itself, not sending messages.